# Bets way to protect direct link?

Tags: htaccess, authentication

I am using Channel Images and obfuscating the links so a user cannot see the path, but I want to protect the full link using htaccess well. The user will be able to see the images, zips, or files in an EE template, but can direct link DL the source as well.

What is the nest way to check if user is logged into EE as a certain membership group before being able to access via a direct link? I have searched and saw that it can be done via an ACT url or a php script, but I have no idea how to write it.

Any existing modules or scripts out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Protected Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/protected-links). This will allow you to limit link usage by IP, Member group, Member ID as well as hotlinking protection (and more I think!)
You can also create links via the CP or have it generate links on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) and [Client Downloads](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/client-downloads). They're both good and coded by trustful developers.